# stabilizable ,detectable and regulator

Tags: control-theory

Assume that $(A_2,B_2)$ is stabilizable and $(C,A)$ is detectable.
Under these conditions, there exist a regulator if the equations

\begin{aligned}
TA_1-A_2T-B_2V&=A_3\\
D_1+D_2T+EV&=0
\end{aligned}

have a solution $(T,V)$.

If $A_1$ is antistable, the solvability of these equations is a necessary condition for a regulator to exist.

Specifically, if for $G:Y\to X$ we have $\sigma(A+GC)\subset\mathbb{C}^{-}$,
and for
$F_2:X\to U$
we have
$\sigma(A_2+B_2F_2)\subset\mathbb{C}^{-}$,
and if  $F_1 :=-F_2T+V$, $F:=(F_1,F_2)$ where $(T,V)$ is a solution  eqution of above then a regulator is given by

\begin{aligned}
\dot{w}&=(A+GC+BF)w(t)-Gy(t)\\
u(t)&=Fw(t).
\end{aligned}

Now I have a question:
Show that if $A_1=a_1$ is scalar with $a_1>0$, then the $a_1$ is a eigenvalue of the matrix $A+GC+BF$?

Comment: Either this is very badly tagged or you should be explaining some terminology and notation, because I am not familiar with most of your terms, nor am I familiar with $\mathbb{C}^-$ (presumably the left half plane?)

Comment: if you not fimiliar to control system theory you cannot solve it !

Comment: Then maybe you should tag it differently, at least with control-theory.

Comment: Its done,thanks

Comment: What is $A_i$, are they part of $A$? What is $B_i$, are they part of the input matrix $B$? What is $E$? There exists a regulator with what property? What is "antisatable" (antistable?, not stable?)? Please provide a more complete background.